# Android App is not responding on click in android studio?

Tags: java, android, button

I am beginner in android studio and When i click on button to transfer my activity from one to another then i am getting error:App is not responding? What's wrong with my code?

Here is first activity which is initial destination

[image]

Here is my Second Activity which is final destination

[image]

Comment: post the error log please

Comment: You already got several answers. In future questions please provide your code **as text** instead of just uploading an screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Your button **b** variable it is bad instantiated, you should declared as follows:

```
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simpleProgramDisplayDate);
```